# What are the two lines for on top of this tower?

Tags: transmission-line

[image]

I have seen other towers with the same lines.

Answer (score 12):

They are earth wires so that lightning hits these before the main AC wires: -

[image]

[Picture source](https://socratic.org/questions/how-are-transmission-lines-protected-from-lightning-strikes)

Comment: Oh, awesome. But isn't the tower a natural grounder, wouldn't a lighting hit the tower anyways?

Or is it to protect the lines between tower-to-towers

Comment: It's not to protect the tower - what would protect the lines between towers if lightning hit?

Comment: Cool, so it's to protect lines between towers

Comment: Yes it is - it acts like a poor man's "faraday cage".

Comment: I wonder how effective these are?

Comment: @copper.hat, You wouldn't see very many of them if they didn't save somebody some money in the long run.